# "Run without debugging" or "Start debugging" giving different result than running script manually

Tags: powershell

The following test sample can be used to reproduce different outcome based on how you run it.
**Prerequisites:** VSCode with PowerShell extension.

**Steps:**

1. Create a new `*.ps1` file on your desktop and paste code below into it.
2. Open file with `VSCode`, bring up terminal and run ex. `.\filename.ps1`

```
$private:PSDefaultParameterValues = @{}
$private:PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("*:ErrorVariable", "+ErrorBuffer")

function Test-Variable
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param ()

    "Test-Variable private: '$($private:PSDefaultParameterValues | Out-String)'"
    "Test-Variable local: '$($local:PSDefaultParameterValues | Out-String)'"
    "Test-Variable script: '$($script:PSDefaultParameterValues | Out-String)'"
    "Test-Variable global: '$($global:PSDefaultParameterValues | Out-String)'"

    $ErrorBuffer = $PSCmdlet.GetVariableValue("ErrorBuffer")
    "Count of errors is $($ErrorBuffer.Count)"

    Write-Error -Message "sample error"

    "Count of errors is $($ErrorBuffer.Count)"
    $ErrorBuffer.Clear()
}

Test-Variable
```

Output is this:

```
> .\filename.ps1
Test-Variable private: ''
Test-Variable local: ''
Test-Variable script: ''
Test-Variable global: ''
Count of errors is 0
Write-Error: C:\Users\User\Desktop\filename.ps1:24:1
Line |
  24 |  Test-Variable
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | sample error
Count of errors is 1
```

Next, instead of running manually in VSCode select from menu `Run -> Run Without Debugging`

And here is the new output:

```
C:\Users\User> . 'c:\Users\User\Desktop\filename.ps1'
Test-Variable private: ''
Test-Variable local: ''
Test-Variable script: '
Name                           Value
----                           -----
*:ErrorVariable                +ErrorBuffer

'
Test-Variable global: '
Name                           Value
----                           -----
*:ErrorVariable                +ErrorBuffer

'
Count of errors is 0
Test-Variable: C:\Users\User\Desktop\filename.ps1:24:1
Line |
  24 |  Test-Variable
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | sample error
Count of errors is 2
```

Suddenly there are now 2 errors!
I understand this is due to `PSDefaultParameterValues` not being respected, global and script scope variable is set even though I explicitly declare it as private.

You can also try `Run -> Start Debugging` and the result is same.

I was pulling my hair for hours trying to figure out what's wrong with my code just to discover this.

The question is, what's the issue and how to resolve it?
Is my code wrong or is there some issue with either `PS extension` or `VSCode`?

My goal is to have this code produce 1 count of errors no matter how I run it.

If you wonder the reason why I use this method, this is how I implement automated logging in PS without having to specify `-ErrorVariable` everywhere, the reason why `PSDefaultParameterValues` is private is because this ensures that only a script being called is seeing it, module scope functions and nested functions will pick it up from the caller (`CmdletBinding` must exist for this to work).

I don't see any other way around, this is just the smallest reproducible sample of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that running your script via the PowerShell extension - whether with or without debugging:

- runs the script with `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) and ...
- ... given that the calling scope is the *global* scope, your script's code effectively runs directly in the global scope.

Therefore, from your function's perspective (which script-internally runs in a *child* scope), the `$script:` and the `$global:` scopes are the same.

---

**Workaround**:

Create a *helper* script alongside your target script, say, `debugHelper.ps1`, with the following content:

```
# Call filename.ps1 in a *child* scope.
& $PSScriptRoot/filename.ps1
```

Then use *it* as the entry point for running or debugging your code.

Comment: Nice, so that's why `$private:` becomes `$global:`, what can I do about this? if debugger can't be configured to not dot source scripts then what else can I do? perhaps some trick in `launch.json`?

Comment: @metablaster, not sure about `launch.json` (haven't looked into it), but there's a simple workaround (though a bit inconvenient) - please see my update.

Comment: This is a clever workaround and yes it's inconvenient, but I already see how could I modify `launch.json` to modify `"script": ""` property to call debug helper script instead of directly dot sourcing. I think I might also file a feature request to PS extension team to implement debugging without dotsourcing. thanks.